# USB Type-C adapters?

Tags: usb, video-adapters

I recently got the new Dell XPS 13 9350. This model features the new USB Type-C; it has no other native port for connecting a display (HDMI, mini DisplayPort, etc..).

I've done my research and there are some adapters available, but the ones I have found are either ridiculously expensive, or have horrible reviews. Several on Amazon from companies I've never even heard of with reviews from people that were given the products for free, which I frankly don't trust at all.

Has anybody had any luck with a good adapter for USB Type-C laptops? I am primarily wanting it to connect to an external NEC 24 inch monitor. It has Display Port and HDMI connections available.

I've found a few like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BSJVY7Y) that have multiple connections in one device, which seems like it would be really convenient. Dell also makes their [own](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=&cs=19&sku=470-ABQN&ST=pla&dgc=ST&cid=297700&lid=5692341&acd=123098073120560&ven1=470-ABQN:51713436948:901pdb6671:c&ven2=:&ven3=812703242058028637) that even includes Ethernet, but it's $75! Some reviews I read talk about BIOS issues that may keep these from working at all (scary).

Is this to be expected since USB Type-C is still fairly new? I feel like there has to be a cheaper and better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of my go-to brands for cables and adapters is Anker and they make a USB-C to HDMI adapter that has some really strong reviews:

[Anker Premium USB-C Hub with HDMI and Power Delivery](https://tr.im/anker_usbc_hub_video_power)

It's best to stay away from "house brands" and brands you have never heard of.  A Google engineer has been testing various USBC cables and has found many which can fry your gear.  Subsequently, [Amazon has banned cheap USB cables.](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/225719-amazon-bans-cheap-usb-c-cables-in-wake-of-google-engineers-crusade).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm probably going to give that one a try, since it is from a reputable brand, and the price isn't bad either! Glad to see Amazon taking action to try and keep the bad usb cables out of circulation.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party on this one, but I can tell you to avoid (at least for now) the Dell docks that may have been recommended to you at the time of your XPS-13 purchase. I tried both docks on two separate XPS-13s, and neither dock worked correctly. The Dell forums are filled with customers angry with the failings of the TB-15 dock, and it's not even offered for sale on their website any longer. However, it is still available on Amazon with no mention of the hardware difficulties, so beware.

I tried the Cable Matters adapter that Allan suggested above, and unfortunately the one I ordered from Amazon arrived DOA.

The one adapter that I did find very useful for me is (Sad to say) Dell's own [DA200 adapter](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=sg&l=en&s=bsd&cs=sgbsd1&sku=470-abnl). It plugs into that USB-C port and gives you an ethernet port, USB3.0, VGA and HDMI ports. Pretty handy and works flawlessly for me every time.

I've also heard some people had great success with the [HooToo Shuttle](http://www.hootoo.com/ht-uc001-usb-type-c-hub-charging-hdmi-apple-pd.html). There are various versions of the Shuttle, one of which has another USB-C port that could be used for charging too. That sounds great, except I really need DisplayPort support.

Overall, I've had this laptop for about three months now and I still can't find an adapter that does exactly what I'm looking for. Hope you do better, and if you do, share it with us!